# WebSocket connection from Unity app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, websocket

I'm writing app that connects to a custom websocket server (socket.io) written in NodeJS.

This server also handles requests from a browser and the browser part works flawlessly, connection, disconnection, messages, all great.

The app part works perfect on Android (tested on samsung s7) and iOS (tested on iPhone6 and 7 with iOS11.3)

Problem is that I need to get it working on headsets like Nibiru and PicoVR, which operative systems are derived from Android (they're a VR version of Android), on these systems, the app works fine, but can't connect to the webserver.

Additional info:

- Server runs on port 7000
- Server also has apache, php and mysql installed
- HTTP connection to server works
- The URL I use for the socket is: "http://192.168.12.1:7000" (server is local, running on port 7000 bc port 80 is taken by apache)
- I'm developing all the apps with Unity3d, version 2017.2.0f3
- Plugin used for WebSockets: [Socket.IO-Unity](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/socket.io-unity)

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by changing the scripting runtime version from "Stable 3.5" to "Experimental 4.6"